# amCharts - How to fill gaps in a data serie with default values?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am receiving a series of data from my backend - some values paired with a specific date.
The data is sometimes inconsistent - i.e. for some dates in a specific range no data is provided.

When rendering a simple line chart, I have an option for amCharts to connect points with a line and not take into acocunt missing data, or to display gaps between points that 'surround' a missing data point.

Is there any **built-in** mechanism to fill such gaps with some default values? I need to display '0' on the Y axis for each gap.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such built-in way to treat gaps in data as zero-value. You'd need to pre-process the data to put those in, either on server- or client-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!